# Unable to patch an object's attribute correctly

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I have a Python module as follows:

```
# src/exec.py

class A:

    def run(self, stuff):
        b = B(stuff.x)

class B:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.obj = self.create_some_obj()
```

I'm trying to test a part of  class `A` independently, for which I need to replace the `obj` in `B` with a fake object. I'm doing this as follows:

```
# test/test_execs.py

import exec as ex

class FakeObjForB:
    def __init__(self):
        # some init

class TestClass:

    @patch.object(ex.B, 'obj', FakeObjForB())
    def test_with_fake_obj(self):
        a = ex.A()
        a.run()
        # assert something about the state of a that depends on the b inside its run method
```

Running this test gives me the error: `AttributeError: <class 'B'> does not have the attribute 'obj'`. I tried replacing the line with the `@patch` decorator with `@patch.object(ex.B, 'obj', FakeObjForB(), create=True)`. This, however, results in `b.obj` using the actual definition, and not `FakeObjForB`, which in turn leads to a false-failure in the assertion in `test_with_fake_obj`. Any clues about what I'm doing incorrectly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you're patching the B class, that's the object passed as the first argument. That class doesn't declare `obj` attribute on the class level and so AttributeError is raised. When you provide `create=True` it won't complain as that argument allows the `obj` attribute to be dynamically created when needed/accessed. But, that won't ever happen as the very first "access" of that attribute is its actual creation - no dynamic mocking ever happened.

A solution is to actually patch the method whose returned value would be assigned to the `obj` attribute, like:

```
@patch.object(ex.B, 'create_some_obj', FakeObjForB())
```